# Как создать N-ое количество ImageView

Tags: swift, xcode

Есть число count(динамическое число), мне необходимо создать count-ое число ImageView. Как это можно реализовать? Или это лучше будет реализовать Collection View?

Comment: Не могли бы вы уточнить зачем вам нужно их создавать? Для этого чтобы показать на экране или просто передать куда-то?

Comment: Мне приходит JSON, где есть ссылки на фотографии и количество самих фотографий, необходимо вывести этот набор фотографий на ControllerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае вы хотите отображать фотографии на `ViewController` загружая их из сети.

Глобально это можно сделать 2 способами:

1. Загрузить все фото и положить в массив `[UIImage]`. Во `ViewController` просто использовать этот массив в `UITableViewDatasouce`.

Недостаток этого подхода в том, что вы не знаете сколько фотографий нужно будет показать, а загружать придется все.

2. Передавать массив ссылок `[URL]` на фотографии во `ViewController`. В таком случае фотографии можно будет загружать только тогда, когда пользователь хочет их смотреть.
   Например для этого подойдет метод `cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?`

Преимущество этого подхода в том, что вы сможете контролировать процесс загрузки каждого фото

Для загрузки изображений можно воспользоваться [Alamofireimage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)

Comment: Не подскажите на счет 2 метода, как называется элемент, куда все фото вкидывать?

Comment: можно просто добавить массив ссылок на фото у ViewController а. В методах UITableViewDatasouce и UITableViewDelegate использовать этот массив

Answer (score 0):

Есть очень классные примеры реализации этого на примере Flickr.
Я реализовывал похоже. Можешь посмотреть в моём репозитории на [GitHub](https://github.com/ELezov/iOS-FlickrSimpleExample)